# spring generating wrong path to forward

Tags: spring-mvc

I have added view resolver to my spring-servlet.xml like this

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

but when i'm running my web application it returns a wrong path as shown in log

```
Forwarding to resource [.jsphello/WEB-INF/jsp/] in InternalResourceView 'hello'
```

whereas it should be `WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch prefix and suffix in your configuration:

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
```

Then it will result in:

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
```

[Prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix) always goes before, while [suffix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix) goes after.